# Step progressbar

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to complete a step progress bar, and on the final node the complete color is not reaching to the end, the finalized color is not being applied:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
  content: counter(stepNum);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active:after {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.multi-steps {
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
.multi-steps > li {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  counter-increment: stepNum;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li:before {
  content: "";
  content: "✓;";
  content: "";
  content: "";
  content: "✓";
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 32px;
  display: block;
  /*margin: 0 auto 4px;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.multi-steps > li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.multi-steps > li:last-child {
  /*&:after{*/
  flex-grow: 0;
  align-items: flex-end;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*display: none;*/
  /*}*/
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
  color: #808080;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <br /><br />
  <ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
    <li>
      <div>Start</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Should be aligned center</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Should be centered too</div>
    </li>
    <li class="is-active">
      <div>Finish step belevie or not</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

on this code I should center the titles of bot nodes and also the "completed" color should reach until the last node. For more detail please refer to my sniped code with [sass](https://codepen.io/the-writer/pen/QWLZVLL)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your line:

```
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active:after {
    background-color: #ededed;
}
```

Which overrides the colour. Simply removing this will add the colour back in:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
  content: counter(stepNum);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.multi-steps {
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
.multi-steps > li {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  counter-increment: stepNum;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li:before {
  content: "";
  content: "✓;";
  content: "";
  content: "";
  content: "✓";
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 32px;
  display: block;
  /*margin: 0 auto 4px;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.multi-steps > li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.multi-steps > li:last-child {
  /*&:after{*/
  flex-grow: 0;
  align-items: flex-end;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*display: none;*/
  /*}*/
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
  color: #808080;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <br /><br />
  <ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
    <li>
      <div>Start</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Should be aligned center</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Should be centered too</div>
    </li>
    <li class="is-active">
      <div>Finish step belevie or not</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: By deleting that part of the code the behavior of the step progress changes, what I did as a work around was to add a css class that overrides the color in that case only when the active node is final.